# Sort object array used in *ngFor with directive

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table with a sort directive that sorts the table based on what header is clicked. However, if the input data has any null values, the sort directive will not work properly.

This is my sort function in the directive:

```
  sortArray (): Array<any> {
    let tempArray: Array<any> = this.data;
    tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
      let aKey = a[this.key];
        let str1: string = a[this.key].toLowerCase();
        let str2: string = b[this.key].toLowerCase();
        if (this.toggleSort) {
          if (str1 < str2) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (str1 > str2) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
        else {
          if (str1 > str2) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (str1 < str2) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
      return 0;
    });
    return tempArray;
  }
```

How can I get this to work on null values?

I have attached a [Stackblitz for this issue.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfuwrc)

Answer (score 1):

```
sortArray (): Array<any> {
    let tempArray: Array<any> = this.data;
    tempArray.sort((a, b) => {
      let aKey = a[this.key];
        let str1: string = a[this.key].toLowerCase();
        let str2: string = b[this.key].toLowerCase();
        if (this.toggleSort) {
          if (!str1 && !str2) {
            return 0;
          } else if (!str1) {
            return 1;
          } else if (!str2) {
            return -1;
          }

          //rest of your logic if neither is null
          if (str1 < str2) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (str1 > str2) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
        else {
          if (str1 > str2) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (str1 < str2) {
            return 1;
          }
        }
      return 0;
    });
    return tempArray;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this works only when the null value is not in the first row.

Comment: Adjust it for your use case?